# Why do the plots not save?

Tags: python

I want to plot my data and save those plots on my computer with a good quality. For some reason, they don't want to unfortunately. Am I missing something basic here?

This is my code:

```
fig = pylab.figure(1)
pylab.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
if all(data_wls) == all(wl1s):
    png_name = "TheSun_Naminus.jpg"
    ax.set_title(r'some title-', fontsize=10)
elif all(data_wls) == all(wl2s):
    png_name = "TheSun_Naplus.jpg"
    ax.set_title(r'some title+', fontsize=10)
else:
    print('unknown data')
ax.plot(wls,fls,'r',lw=0.5)
ax.plot(data_wls, data_fls ,'b',lw=0.5)
#then I set up axes and stuff
plt.savefig(png_name, dpi=300, quality=95, optimize=True)
    
pylab.show()
```

When I look into my directory, no new file with the title can be found.
I'm glad for any advice, you can give me, thank you!

Comment: I suspect that the script is quite simply not being run in the directory that you imagine it is. `print(os.getcwd())` might be enlightening...

Comment: Hi.. Are you able to get the desired plot??

Comment: not yet. I'm currently trying alaniwi's hint!

Comment: The directory should be right, but I can't find the plot

Comment: The plot thickens... what do you get if you test for the output file's existence immediately after the `savefig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can not comment I'll reuse this answer:

Instead of printing the working directory using you can also just specify the output directory for your plots and see if that works.

Comment: oh, that makes sense, thank you! That's because I've been working on the script for a while and tried different things. I should change it for sure!

Comment: I would delete my answer since it is wrong but I don't want to delete your comments.

Comment: Sorry my comment is in the wrong place, I will move it to under the question and then you can delete the answer. (Now done.)

Comment: Changing it to the specific path appeared to solve the problem, thank you!